# Throw expression reordering in C++?

Tags: c++, exception

**In C++, can two throw expressions, or expressions around throw expression be reordered?**

For example, in the following code:

```
int f(int x) {
  if (! (x >= 0))
    throw std::range_error("argument must be non-negative");
  return pure_sqrt(x);
}

inf g(int y) {
  if (! (y > 0))
    throw std::range_error("argument must be positive");
  return pure_invsqrt(y);
}

void test(int x, int y) {
  try {
    int a = f(x);
    int b = g(y);
    return a + b;
  } catch (std::exception e) {
    std::cout << "Error: " << e.what() << "." << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Assuming both `x == -1` and `y == -1`, can the exception from `g` ("argument must be positive") be thrown before the exception from `f`?

That is, can pure functions (except from their throwing behaviour) be reordered, or are uncaught exception considered as observable behaviour by the remaining of the `try` block?

Comment: Are you asking: "Can throw expression be reordered?

Comment: Note that real-world code should catch the exception by **reference**, not by **value**.

Comment: @Oliv Yes. Also, can a side-effect free operation and an expression be reordered? Maybe here it is legal to compute `!(y > 0)` in advance, before throwing the exception for `x`?

Comment: @PeteBecker Oops, sorry for that.

Comment: @Nonyme, So you should change or rephrase this sentence, "In c++, are uncaught exceptions guaranteed to execude in order?" because it seems not to be understood the way you meant. Probably the reason why you have been down voted, and the answers posted from now. Your question is a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to the question, "Can a compiler reorder throw expressions, or expressions around a throw expressions?" The answer is, it depends on what *observable behavior* these expressions will be the cause.

The compiler must produce an assembly that followes a rule often named "as if rule". To simplify, this rule states that the compiler can not change the meaning of your code in a way that would change its *observable behavior*. It is explained in this [section](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution) of the c++ standard (reading the entire chapter, is a good advice). An *observable behavior* is defined as following:

> - Accesses through volatile glvalues are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.
> - At program termination, all data written into files shall be identical to one of the possible results that execution of the program according to the abstract semantics would have produced.
> - The input and output dynamics of interactive devices shall take place in such a fashion that prompting output is actually delivered before a program waits for input.
>   What constitutes an interactive device is implementation-defined.

Inside your code exemple, an exception thrown during the execution of `f` or `g` will be caught by the catch clause, and then the exception message is outputed. If a compiler were reordering the call to `f` and `g`, it will change the "observable behavior" of your code.

But the compiler, or the CPU, can still reorder other instructions around the throw expressions, as long as this does not change the observable behavior. For exemple extructions could be run in this order:

```
int test(int x, int y) { 
  //I made some typo fix to your code assuming that test should return int or rethrow.
    bool f_precondition = (x >= 0);
    bool g_precondition = (y > 0);
  try {
    if (! f_precondition){
      throw std::range_error("argument must be non-negative");
    if (! g_precondition)
      throw std::range_error("argument must be positive");
  } catch (std::exception e) {
    std::cout << "Error: " << e.what() << "." << std::endl;
    throw;
  }
  return pure_sqrt(x) + pure_invsqrt(y);
}
```

A smart compiler could also elide the throw -> catch path;

---

In the list of observable behavior, notice the abscence of read or write to atomic variable.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

When an exception is thrown in a `try` block, execution immediately jumps to the closest matching `catch` statement on the call stack, and does not execute the rest of the code in the `try` block. If you want to check both functions `f` and `g`, you need to put them in different `try` blocks.

Answer (score 2):

No. When f throws the execution continues in the catch block. g is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

No, they cannot be reordered, as standard does not explicitely allow to do it, and as-if rule cannot be applied here, as it would change observable behavior of the program.

For example, by checking `x` and `y` value, you can determine which exception **should** be thrown, and by examining exception object, you can determine which exception **was** thrown.

Comment: Ok. So, checking for exception is facultative in the sense that, if I want to enforce that no exception occurred before engaging into a costly computation, I do not need to catch it. There is no way to throw unordered exceptions?